# My Wordpress, Bootstrap theme is not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on Wordpress theme using Bootstrap on localhost.
I have load the CSS files correctly and I have load the js files using the right way but for some reasons js scripts is not working.

Here is my index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is my header.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href = "<?php bloginfo(stylesheet_url); ?>" rel = "stylesheet">

</head>


<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Here is my footer.php

```html
<script src= "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This problem drives me CRAZY! 
I spent 2 hours searching for solution but nothing!

So what is the problem guys?

Comment: Use the proper enqueue (`wp_enqueue_script`) functions, don't manually add script tags - it's a bad habit

Comment: Can you explain to me how to use it?

Comment: `I have load the CSS files correctly`, how are you so sure? Because for what I know you didn't

Comment: I can know, because CSS changes appears in my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it for including your scripts

```
function WM_Scripts(){

    wp_register_script( 'jScript', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' );
    wp_register_script('bootstrapjs',get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jScript' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'WM_Scripts' );
```

And For stylesheet you have to use this function.

```
function WM_CSS(){
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrapGrid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapGrid' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'WM_CSS' );
```

Please refer wordpress documentation for include your script into footer.
This the right way to include your script and styles.
And please add wp_head(); functions in your header to load script and styles.

Comment: Note that this doesn't load anything to the footer, you will have to set the last parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` to `true` for that to happen. Good job promoting enqueue though!

Comment: Yes i know that i said already for that to  refer WordPress documentation for include your script into footer.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your *"functions.php"* file to enqueue *"/css/bootstrap.min.css"*, *"/style.css"* and your *"/js/bootstrap.js"*:

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script(
            'bootstrapjs',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js',
            array(),
            '3.3.5', // Bootstrap version number
            true // Place before </body>
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Keep note, you need to set the last parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` to `true` to place your *'/js/bootstrap.js'* before the `</body>` end tag. For more info visit [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: ALWAYS use wp_enqueue_script/wp_register_script

Comment: This is not enqueue, this is adding a function to the `wp_footer` action.

Comment: @Tim Hey, this is working.. Is using `add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_script_footer')` a bad idea?

Comment: @5ervant, Yes. wp_enqueue_script links a script file to the generated page at the right time according to the script dependencies, if the script has not been already included and if all the dependencies have been registered.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Jup, the worst of all when it comes to loading Javascript to WordPress pages.

Comment: @Tim The new update is the way I enqueue my _"bootstrap.min.css"_ and my _"stylesheet"_ in my developing theme. I don't know why my _"bootstrap.min.js"_ is still separated from them, maybe because my theme is under construction.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Thanks to you both, I'm now putting my enqueue scripts and styles in the same place. I also update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `echo`. You must print what the function `get_template_directory_uri()` returns like here:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

After that your js will work flawless.